# Select only those seminars, that are not attached to a particular student

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Suppose we have `Student` `belongsToMany` `Seminar` relationship defined. How to select only those seminars, that are not attached to a **particular** student?

Comment: You mean to get all seminars that do not have any students participating?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova No, I want to get all seminars that do not have **one particular student** participating in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$seminars = Seminar::whereDoesntHave('students', function($q) use ($studentId) {
  $q->where('seminar_student.student_id', $studentId);
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. This code errors with `PHP error:  Undefined variable: studentId on line 1`

Comment: @AlexanderLomia that's because you should define `$studentId`. Also **on line 1**? Where did you put this code?

Comment: That's true. You need to have student's ID in a variable.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Your solution works like a charm, thank you!